# Javascript ribbon hidden behind invisible box

Tags: javascript, overlay, ribbon, expand

So I have two images, one is a half of a ribbon and the second one is a full ribbon with facebook etc links on it. I need to have the first one in the middle of a page, so when you click it it would expand out. I figured i need to use hidden overlay or something but I am totally new at javascript.

Can someone provide an example or help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand what you want and tell me if this is what you meant.

You can wrap the two images in two sepatare divs and then wrap them in a div with position relative.

Then you give to the two divs position absolute.

On the click of the first div you change the second div left position (or the top if you want a vertical effect).

Here is the html with divs only:

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div id="frontDiv">
        aaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
    <div id="backDiv">
        bbbbbbbbbbb
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the CSS:

```
#frontDiv{
    height: 20px; width: 45px; 
    background: red; position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 0px;
}

#backDiv{
    height: 20px; width: 30px; 
    background: blue; position: absolute; 
    z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px;
}
```

And here the javascript (in jQuery):

```
$("#frontDiv").click(function(){
    $("#backDiv").animate({"left":"45px"}, 300); //{"top":"20px"} for vertical effect
});
```

At the end you can position the wrapper div wherever you want.

Full example at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w7RVe/

Comment: Not quite but this helps me explain my problem. What i ment was that there 2 actual images. One needs to be shown at all times and the other should slide out when the first one is clicked, kind of like bb slides out of aa. I figured i need something to cover up the second picture behind it before the first one is clicked but I might be wrong, thanks for trying

Comment: I'm adding a picture to help explain: http://www.upload.ee/image/3640353/ribbons.png

Comment: @user2485439 I updated the script, can you check if this is what you want? [http://jsfiddle.net/w7RVe/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/w7RVe/2/)

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i was going for, big thanks man. I will have to figure out how to make it slide back on second click or something and how to make those logos in there links but now i got the framework. Again, THANKS!

Comment: IF you wouldn't mind, maybe you could tell me the line which would retract the second image upon clickin anywhere else on the page?

Comment: @user2485439 for the links you should consider using a map, to retract the ribbon you need to set a `click()` event on the target and call `$("#backDiv").animate({"left": "-318px"}, 300);`, this way you reset it to its initial position.

Comment: yeah, I found an image mapper and that did the trick, however I'm hopeless at javascript so I got some trying to do with that bit :) thank you though